# Regex to find a class in a list of files

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I have a list of files (HTML) that contains classes.

```
 1    <div class="homepage">...</div>
 2    <div class="abc homepage">...</div>
 3    <div class="abc homepage2">...</div>
 4    <div class="abc homepage four five">...</div>
 5    <div class="abc homepagenot five">...</div>
 6    <div class="abc homepage-not five">...</div>
```

I'm trying to use regex to find it in Visual Studio using Regex Expressions.

I've been trying to use

```
class=".*homepage.*"
```

as the search criteria, but that is also returning me point 5,6.

Essentially I just want point 1, 2, 4.

What am I missing in regex?

Comment: It doesn't work, because it also matches on `homepage2`, `homepagenot` and `homepage-not` which are not desired matches.

Answer (score 1):

You could check for the existence of a word boundary with `\b` which looks for a non-word character (and can be zero length). I also include a negative lookahead for the hyphen, because a hyphen is a non-word character that will match on `\b` but you don't want item 6 in your list.

```
\bhomepage\b(?!-)
```

Here's the [Regex101 page](https://regex101.com/r/Z8snpE/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try `class=".*homepage[ "]`. This looks for either a space or quote right after `homepage`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to find single word homepage within class="...".
Please see [this](https://regex101.com/r/mEUDFg/3) regex.

```
class=\"(.+ )*homepage( .+)*\"
```

Comment: Include the regex in your post to avoid link-rot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want only first 4 divs as matches, this expression will work for you.

```
homepage(?!not|-)(.*?)
```

```js
var divs ="<div class='homepage'></div>"
 +"<div class='abc homepage'></div>"
 +"<div class='abc homepage2'></div>"
 +"<div class='abc homepage four five'></div>"
 +"<div class='abc homepagenot five'></div>"
 +"<div class='abc homepage-not five'></div>"
 +"<div class='abc homepage2'></div>";

var matches = divs.match(/(homepage)(?!not|-)(.+?)/g);

console.log(matches, matches.length);
```